# Solutions to Bessel Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

Just a sort of general question, but when solving Bessel DE's, for example for only integer values of n, do you usually just leave them in the form of
$$y(x) = AJ_n(x)+B Y_n(x)$$
or do you actually simplify the answers/put them in the form of summations? If you'd have to do the second option, for, let's say order $0$, or order $1$, how would one compute the limits in the $Y_n(x)$ part?

I'm really sorry if this seems like a dumb question btw, it's just that everywhere I look, I only see the solutions in the form of the equation that I wrote above, but no expansion/simplification anywhere.

Edit: removed an incorrect assumption that $Y_0=0$.

Comment: Depends what you're doing next, really. It is true that in practice there is less freedom than the equation makes it look like there is because of the need to avoid singularities.

Comment: Also $Y_0$ is definitely not identically zero, I'm not sure where you got that idea.

Comment: Ah, as an answer to your second comment, I looked at it closer and I just realized where my mind went wrong /)_-. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll edit my post accordingly. Also, for your first comment, could you explain exactly what you mean? Or, if it's no trouble, could you give me an idea about where I could read more into this? I'm taking a course for applied math methods and I've found our class notes to be not very detailed or helpful, so I'm usually left really confused about smaller details of things. :/

Comment: Honestly this is too broad for me to give a general statement. If you can give some context about what you might be doing next then I might be able to help you. If you want to just soak in exposition, I have to suggest Watson *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*. It's almost 100 years old now, so it doesn't have any modern graphics, and it predates a lot of more modern machinery so its methodology is basically brute force from time to time. But the presentation of theory is great.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this! I didn't realize there'd be this much theory on one class of functions, but honestly, this is really cool! So honestly, regarding my question, I was curious about why I've currently only seen people write out the solutions to the general Bessel DE's of different orders in the form that I've written above, rather than as a simplified (to an extent) equation. Of course, this might be only related to what I've seen until now, and not an actual thing, but I kind of wanted to confirm what is usually done in cases like this, if that makes sense?

Comment: I mean you can't find the coefficients without the boundary conditions, and a series expansion isn't really "simpler". There is some question about why this particular fundamental set of solutions, though. Up to scale there is a nice simple answer to that: $J_n$ is as nice at the origin as it can be.

Comment: Ahh yes yes of course, I'm talking generally, without any given boundary conditions. I do think I'll look into this a little more and see what I can understand on my own. This particular set of solutions comes from Frobenius' method, right?

Comment: I think you can obtain $J_n$ from the Frobenius method and then $Y_n$ is developed from reduction of order.